# my selenium driver keeps crashing even though it gets me to the page i want but crashes before it can click the download buttonn

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.nasdaq.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="find-symbol-input"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="find-symbol-input"]'))).clear()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "find-symbol-input").send_keys("GLD")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/div/div/a[1]'))).click()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/main/div[2]/div[4]/div/section/div/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a/span"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/main/div[2]/div[4]/div/section/div/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a/span"))).clear()
```

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="table-tabs__tab table-tabs__tab--active"]'))).click()
driver.quit()
** not sure what i am doing wrong any feedback is helpful thank you**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed